# Adding Sudo Permission to a user

Tags: linux, sudo, users

I am trying to add sudo permission for a user to login as a different user. Currently I am looking for below scenario.

For eg: If "Sam" need to login as "Scott" using sudo access then what are all the command that I need to run using root ID.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work, to enable sam to become scott using sudo. Replace last "ALL" with specific commands sam can run as scott.

```
sam ALL(scott) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: Is this a command? or I need to add this in /ect/sudoers

Comment: Add this to /etc/sudoers. Just type ```visudo``` and below line ```root = ALL(ALL) ALL``` add the line in the answer

Comment: Its asking me password when I do sudo su - scott. How to grant sudo permission without asking password

Comment: Change line to ```sam = ALL(scott) NOPASSWD: ALL```

Comment: I have already tried that one but I am getting syntax error.

Comment: Typo, its NOPASSWD:ALL

Comment: still getting a syntax error  sam = ALL(scott) NOPASSWD:ALL

Comment: Is your user sam or Sam

Comment: its sam only but in the script the wheel syntax is like below %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: Then remove line for sam, and add yourself to wheel group

Comment: Wont it give permission to all other user groups?

Comment: No, if you add yourself to wheel group, you will get its permissions, thats all. No other users will get it

Comment: I mean to say, if I add sam to wheel group then he can access to scott , tiger, eric users directory as well.

Comment: Silly me, i edited answer. = is not needed

Comment: Mark it as answered if it is done

Comment: still getting syntax error

Comment: Have you tried without NOPASSWD:

Comment: yes but getting same error